# Network configuration for Fortmatic on 'ropsten' -- typescript

Tags: web3js, typescript

So I am trying to configure the the ropsten network by injecting the fortmatic provider into web3, but am getting these errors. My code is exactly how they have it in their documentation, so idk why I am getting these errors (shown in the image provided) :

```
export const fortmatic_ropsten = new Fortmatic('my api key', 'ropsten');   
window.web3 = new Web3(fortmatic_ropsten.getProvider())
```

[image: typescript errors]

it looks like the fortmatic provider contains slightly different parameters that web3 uses. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out web3 does not work too well with typescript. I just put this code in a .js file instead of .tsx and it works fine now.